# Batch file to check for a specific motherboard ID

Tags: batch-file, cmd, hwid

So I'm making a spoofer that changes a lot of network stuff and hwids but I want to make it private or sell it and so I'm making a system that checks against a txt on my server for motherboard IDs (`wmic baseboard get serialnumber`) and if it's different it just exits and if it matches one of the IDs I put then it lets it continue. Would anyone know if how or how this is possible?
FYI I'm making this in a batch file because I feel It's unnecessary to make a console project just for a few cmd commands

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims== " %%A in ('wmic baseboard get serialnumber /value ^| find /i "SerialNumber="') do set serialnumber=%%A
if /i not "%serialnumber%" == "PF0TPMUN" goto :exit
```

Just made it check the serial number from the command and exit if it's different